# Index of Min of each line in a matrix without loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, min

I work on a matrix like this :

```
A=[1,2,3;5,4,6;9,8,7];
```

I want to get the index of each line. Here it is : `Index = [1;2;3]`

But how can I get this without a loop ?

I do this for the moment :

```
for k=1:length(A)
    [~,Index(k)] = min(A(k,:));
end
```

Comment: `[values,index]=min(A,[],2)`

Comment: See [`min`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html):

> `M = min(A,[],dim)` returns the smallest elements along dimension `dim`. For example, if `A` is a matrix, then `min(A,[],2)` is a **column vector containing the minimum value of each row**.

Looking at output options, you can see

> `[M,I] = min(___)` finds the indices of the minimum values of `A` and returns them in output vector `I`.

You were already using the second part of the above documentation notes, so just combine the two...

```
A=[1,2,3; 5,4,6; 9,8,7];
[~, idx] = min(A, [], 2);
% result: idx = [1; 2; 3];
```